# c# substring method error when setting end parameter

Tags: c#, string, exception, substring

I am trying to extract part of a string from itself. I get de string from an http request. I want to slice from position `17`, to its `Length - 3`. Here is my code in c#:

```
var response = await responseURI2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Debug.WriteLine(response);
Debug.WriteLine(response.GetType());
Debug.WriteLine(response.Length);
int length = (response.Length) - 3;
Debug.WriteLine(length);
try{
    var zero = response.Substring(17, length);
    Debug.WriteLine(zero);
}
catch
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Not able to do substring");
}
```

This is the output:

```
[0:] "dshdshdshdwweiiwikwkwkwk..."
[0:] System.String
[0:] 117969
[0:] 117966
[0:] Not able to do substring
```

Any ideas of why it cannot do Substring correctly? If I only do response.Substring(17) it works ok. However, when I try to cut from the end, it fails.

Comment: Perhaps you can figure this out when you remove the catch and just read the exception that is thrown.

Comment: Say you have a string that is 21 characters long. Your code says "the length is 18" (21 - 3 = 18). Then you're saying "give me 18 characters from position 17 onwards." 18 + 17 = 35, the string only contains 21, Houston, we have a problem.

Comment: You should probably [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32)).

Comment: Thanks, i should have read the docs indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with *indexes*, say, you want to obtain substring from `17`th position up to `3`d from the end, you can use *ranges* instead of `Substring`:

```
var zero = response[17..^3];
```

If you insist on `Substring` you have to do the arithmetics manually:

```
var zero = response.Substring(17, response.Length - 17 - 3);
```

Comment: That's the best way, i forgot about ranges since i still cant work with C#8. But to make your answer complete you need to mention that OP used the second parameter of Substring like it was for the endIndex(so needs endIndex - startIndex to calculate length).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0):

```
public string Substring (int startIndex, int length);
```

`Substring` takes the parameters `int startIndex` and `int length`

When you don't start from the beginning of the string, you need calculate the remaining length by deducting the startIndex from your `length`.

Try

```
var zero = response.Substring(17, length - 17);
```